# How to fire an selection event from another function [SAPUI5]

Tags: javascript, xml, binding, sapui5

i want to know how to select and fire an (CheckBox) selection Event from another method, as if to simulate a selection of the CheckBox with the selectionFunction in place.

I do have the following CheckBoxes:

```
  <VBox>
    <CheckBox select="onSelectFirstCheckBox" />
    <CheckBox select="onSelectSecondCheckBox" />
  </VBox>
```

with two accopanying methods:

```
onSelectionFirstCheckBox: function(oEvent) {
  console.log("Hello World");
  //From here select the second checkBox + trigger it's selection method
},

onSelectionSecondCheckBox: function(oEvent) {
  console.log("Hello World");
}
```

**Question**: When selecting the first `CheckBox` and being subsequently in the `onSelectionFirstCheckBox` i want to select the second `CheckBox` and also trigger it's method: `onSelectionSecondCheckBox`. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

you can always grab the instance of the "other" checkbox and fire the event:

```
oOtherCheckBox = ...;
// select the other checkbox
oOtherCheckBox.setSelected(true); 
// fire select event so event handlers can handle the change
oOtherCheckBox.fireSelect({selected:true});
```

as to how to grab the other checkbox, you can either traverse to parent from `oEvent.getSource()` and then down to children, relying on strucure of the view, or give it an id and get from the view by id: `this.getView().byId(id of the other checkbox)`

Comment: Generated `fire*`-methods are _protected_ i.e. not intended to be used in application development.